# How do you create a functionnal desktop folder after deleting it?

Tags: desktop, mate-desktop

On Mate desktop I accidentally did a rm -rf * in home folder, now every file that I create inside this folder appears on the Desktop, I created a new Desktop folder but it's not enough to fix it.

Comment: You can't restore from your backup?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Comment: thanks, I did not see the answers here but reinstalled Unbuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also struggled to find the answer. Posting this answer so that it will help someone in the future.

1. Create a new "Desktop" folder,
2. Open the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`
3. Change the entry `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"` to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`
4. Reboot the computer.

(This method can also be used if you have accidentally deleted your Desktop, Downloads, Pictures folder etc. which are commonly found in Linux distros.)

Answer (score 2):

The `Desktop` folder is not some hard-coded name that automagically links your actual desktop with your `~/Desktop` directory.

Since you have deleted all your data, it's probably better to remove your current user, recreate it and start again (or restore from a backup). If this is the only user, it would probably be best done whilst signed on as root.